# "sign in to google" eclipse kepler button does'nt opens the google login window?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, authentication

I am using Eclipse Kepler With Google App Engine v1.9.10 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine. On clicking "sign in to google" it does not opens the login window it shows error the below mentioned error

"Unable to load page
Problem occurred while loading the URL https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=130316539331.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo%23email

Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()". 
Can anyone please help. I have apps to be uploaded to GAE. Is there any way that i could build apps in eclipse and then upload them from the ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ubuntu 12.04

1. Open System Settings
2. Select Network.
3. Select Network Proxy.
4. Set Method to None

and voila...google login link opens in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your app using the command line as follows [1]:

```
appcfg.sh update myapp/war
```

or for a Python or PHP app [2]:

```
appcfg.py update myapp/
```

The proxy hostname error seems to be related to your system proxy settings (off-topic for StackOverflow) however you can try setting the 'no_proxy' environment variable before launching Eclipse as a workaround:

```
export no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost
eclipse &
```

[1] [Uploading and Managing a Java App](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp)
[2] [Uploading, Downloading, and Managing a Python App](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp)